# How to expect a boolean prop in my Vue unit test using mocha/chai?

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, mocha.js, chai

Using [Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/) I have a unit test that I am trying to check for a true/false that looks like this:

```
describe('The thing', () => {
    it('must be available.', () => {
        const available = true
        const wrapper = shallowMount(MyVueComponent, {
            propsData: { available },
        })
        expect(wrapper).to.be.true
    })
})
```

When I run `npm run test:unit`

I get the following:

> AssertionError: expected { Object (isFunctionalComponent, _emitted, ...) } to be true

If I just check the value of `available`, then it's all good. But that seems like I'm doing it wrong.

Other tests I have written are working fine as I am checking for a text value:

```
describe('The thing', () => {
    it('should have a name.', () => {
        const name = 'Hal'
        const wrapper = shallowMount(MyVueComponent, {
            propsData: { name },
        })
        expect(wrapper.text()).to.include(name)
    })
})
```

I am not sure how to check that the `available` is a boolean and it must be `true`. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

**EDIT**

This is what my Vue component looks like:

```
export default {
    name: 'MyVueComponent',
    props: {
        name: String
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            available: true,
        }
    },
}
```

**EDIT 2**

This seems to work in my unit test:

```
describe('The thing', () => {
    it('must be available.', () => {
        const available = true
        const wrapper = shallowMount(MyVueComponent, {
            propsData: { available },
        })
        expect(wrapper.vm.available).to.be.true
    })
})
```

However, it is looking at my actual component in my `/src` directory. If I change the data values from `true` to `false` my tests come out correctly. I'm not sure how to have the data stay at the test level. So if I were to change `const available = false`, my test should fail--but it does not.

**EDIT 3**

It seems like this works (to access the data object):

```
describe("The thing", () => {
  it("must be available.", () => {
    const defaultData = MyVueComponent.data();
    // const wrapper = shallowMount(MyVueComponent, {});
    expect(defaultData.available).to.be.true;
  });
});
```

But it still seems not right that I'm referencing my actual code, and not sticking within the unit tests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to check the received prop, which you can do with [`wrapper.props()`](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/props.html)

```js
describe('The thing', () => {
    it('must be available.', () => {
        const available = true
        const wrapper = shallowMount(MyVueComponent, {
            propsData: { available },
        })
        expect(wrapper.props().available).to.be.true
        // or: 
        // expect(wrapper.props().available).to.equal(available)
    })
})
```

Chai's [`.to.be.true`](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#true) and [`.to.equal`](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#equalval-msg) use `===` so there is no need to separately check that it is indeed a Boolean, but if you prefer the "expressiveness" of it, you can check it too:

```js
expect(wrapper.props().available).to.be.a('boolean')
```

Comment: Ah - thank you so much for the help! (Obviously) this is my first attempt at TDD. It looks like I need to dig into the `data` property of my component to get the value of `available`. I've updated my question to show what my component looks like.